# Highlighting text in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on making a Firefox extension, and I am interested in programmatically highlighting sequences of text in the website as part of my larger extension, similarly to how [Google Chrome's NaturalReader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/naturalreader-ai-text-to/kohfgcgbkjodfcfkcackpagifgbcmimk) does. I have very little experience with JavaScript and HTML DOM.

I have come across [mark.js](https://markjs.io/), but I cannot figure out how to actually include it in my Firefox extension, other than literally just copy and paste the code from the `dist/mark.js` file (See the > 1000 line file [here](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/blob/master/dist/mark.js)) directly above my code in the `parseHTML.js` file (see below).

I made the following code, which is called by the popup when you click on the extension icon, to try and make `mark.js` work, more specifically highlight all the text, one element at a time. I am getting the text from the website to properly print out in the console, but none of the text on the website actually highlights. The popup appears as expected as well when I click on the icon.

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "myName"
"version": "1.0",
"description": "myDescription",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "48": "icons/brain.jpg"
    },
    "default_title": "myName",
    "default_popup": "popup/player.html",
    "browser_style": true
},
"icons": {
    "48": "icons/brain.jpg"
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
]
}
```

**So, in conclusion I have two distinct questions. The first one is "How do I properly include mark.js to be a part of my popup script?" and the second one is "Why is markRanges simply doing nothing at all when I click on my icon?".** My goal is to make a script that runs when the user clicks on the icon, and that script is called parseHTML.js, and it makes use of functions in mark.js. parseHTML is called first by player.js, because parseHTML.js needs to manipulate things which are on the webpage itself, while player.js only has the ability to manipulate things which are inside of the popup box which appears when the icon is clicked.

Could someone give me some guidance on this problem?

```js
//popup/player.js
browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "parseHTML.js"});

//popup/parseHTML.js
/* copy the over 1000 lines of code from dist/mark.js right here, above my own code in this parseHTML.js file. */
var root = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
runChildren(root.item(0));

function highlightNode(node)
{
    var instance = new Mark(node);
    const ranges = [{ start: 0, end: node.textContent.length }];
    instance.markRanges(ranges);
    console.log(node.textContent);
}

function runChildren(node)
{
    let alreadyDone = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        if(!alreadyDone && node.childNodes[i].nodeName == "#text")
        {
            alreadyDone = true;
            highlightNode(node);
        }
        runChildren(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

```css
/* popup/player.css */
html,
body {
    width: 100px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}


button {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 3% auto;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #E5F2F2;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #CFF2F2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="popup-content">
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- <script src="mark.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> -->
<script src="player.js"></script>

</html>
```